# How can I load a route without building it every time?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I'm  developing a flutter app which has a inbox message view. I'm loading this message route as a widget inside my main navigation route. When I calling this message widget, it is building as new every time I select inbox option.

i.e. "initState" is calling every time. I need to load the widget only once and return the already loaded widget when I press inbox option in navigation drawer.

Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

YES! but you should read. [flutter state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt).
I'm recommending [State rebuilder](https://pub.dev/packages/states_rebuilder).

Without state management every time you call setState() it will call the build() methods and rebuild everything.

Comment: that library is sooo ugly

Comment: I respect your opinion. :) @Eugene

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have a different understanding from what "loading" a widget actually means.

Are you doing expensive work in your `initState()`? That should be done in the background by your business logic (there are numerous discussions which architecture is the best fit for your purpose, options are [BLoC](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc), [MVC](https://pub.dev/packages/mvc_pattern), [ScopedModel](https://pub.dev/packages/scoped_model) to name a few).

`initState()` is in charge of initialization when your widget is inserted into the widget tree (which happens to take place on navigating to the page, and again when you come back since the widget gets removed from the tree after you leave). Performing heavy/business logic-related operations here might not be the most ideal place to do so.

Comment: I just need to start a Timer function inside the initState. But this cause multiple Timer functions executing each time i am loading that route.

Comment: can you elaborate on what that timed function does, exactly?

Comment: timefunction checks sharedpreference for new messages to update in message view. Each time new message comes in server side, i will send push notification to the app and inside app i will store this into sharedpreference as json.

Comment: wouldn't this make more sense as a function set up on app start then?
as mentioned before, widget/screen lifecycle methods might not be the best place to use for running your business logic. you're adding coupling this way that makes your app harder to understand (even if it's just you working on it) & test.